Word information vs. word frequency in a text
I am looking for a basic mathematical model of information encoded in a text.
For the sake of presentation I adopt a language learner perspective: how many words does one need to know, in order to understand a book (provided that one knows the basic grammar or at least morphology)? An example given here (the first installment of Harry Potter in Hebrew) contains the main features of the problem:

The most frequent words are prepositions, conjunctions, auxiliary verbs, etc. that by themselves carry little information (or no information at all).
Most of the words occur only once. These are clearly informative ones, but anyone who has ever learned a language knows that one does not need to know all the words to understand a book - in fact, at a certain level one learns new words by encountering them. Moreover, most second language speakers vocabulary remains a fraction of that of native speakers, without significantly hampering their ability to interact with natives.

These features are summarized by Zipf's law and/or rarefaction curves. I suppose these could be combined with the Shannon theory of information to relate the information content understood with the size of the reader's vocabulary.
I would particularly appreciate references to books or original articles.

The notion of how many words you need to understand a book has two variables at least: age group and the subject matter. Harry Potter is not a book on microbes.

@Lambie technical literature is often easier.

https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-vocabulary/top-3000-words/ AND https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/external/pdf/wordlists/oxford-3000-5000/American_Oxford_3000.pdf It's already done.

@Lambie this is just a frequently list, whereas I am asking for a mathematical model.

While prepositions et al carry no information in isolation, if you removed them from a text you would quickly notice that that is not the case in their actual usage. There are different kinds of information, lexical and structural among others. Function words provide information about the relationships between other words.

@OliverMason yes, I agree with that: a preposition reduces the uncertainty about what follows, making it more predictable. So the preposition carries some information, while the word that follows it adds less (and at some point becomes guessable - hence we need not have 100% knowledge of vocabulary, if we understand the structure.)

"how many words does one need to know": Those sites provide the answer to this question. Anyway, when you read a book, it's not about individual words. You have to understand to parse utterances, not individual words.

@Lambie you might be are confusing linguistics (specifically stochastic grammars in this case) with discourse theory (aka parsing utterances).

No, I am not the one confusing anything at all. For all your top heavy qualifications, I find this question to be naive in the extreme, quite frankly.  You are the one talking about words and their frequency and how many you need to read a book. Knowledge of individual words is not how books are read. Readers read books (or any written text) by parsing chunks of text* A mathematical model for understanding the text of a book requires defining of those chunks.  One can study atoms or quarks but that doesn't explain gravity, does it? And believe me, I know just about zero about that.

@Lambie let's move on beyond the things already contained in the Q.? Also, please tell me more about how books produce utterances.

All written text (i.e. books) contain utterances. Written language just reflects the real or spoken language (natural language speech). Spoken language is made up of utterances (largest unit). So, you have to decide how you will divide that up. The people who have done the most work on this are the automatic translation and speech recognition folks.

Are you aware of TF-IDF?
